# Aggregating data on monthly basis

Tags: r, datetime, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I do have following data in R:

```
           date          category1  category2   category 3  category 4
1    2012-04-01            7496.00   77288.37  224099.15     700050.04
2    2012-04-02           24541.00   59103.94  138408.65     625006.84
3    2012-04-03            1249.00   15951.50  574170.30     249390.53
4    2012-04-04            5205.00   10866.00       0.00     358703.88
5    2012-04-05           10398.00       0.00  119745.17     270585.46
```

And use following script to aggregate data on monthly basis:

```
data <- as.xts(data$category1,order.by=as.Date(data$date))
monthly <- apply.monthly(data,sum)
monthly
```

**Question**: Instead of repeating the step each for every category and then joining each monthly dataframe, how can I apply `as.xts(...)` to all columns? I tried

```
as.xts(c("data$category1","data$category1"),order.by=as.Date(data$date))
```

which did not work.

Also: Is there a better way to aggregate on a monthly basis?

Answer (score 0):

Use `xts` instead of `as.xts`.

```
apply.monthly(xts(df[ -1], order.by = as.Date(df$date)), mean)
```

However, this seems to only work for mean, not for sum. You can always use `sapply` to iterate through the columns

```
 sapply(colnames(data[, -1]), function(x) apply.monthly(as.xts(data[,x],
                                                       order.by=as.Date(data$date)),sum))
```

Comment: That only helped to get the -1th column. I would need all columns, or be able to select them. Like `as.xts(c("data$category1","data$category1"),order.by=as.Date(data$date))` , which unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: Update my answer - For some reason it works with `mean`, but not with `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `daily2monthly` function in the HydroTSM package.  It can handle more than just xts for arguments, including multiple columns.  `Fun` can be `sum` or `mean`.

```
monthly <- daily2monthly(data, FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```